# javascript variable to php variable

Tags: javascript, php

How to assign javascript variable to php $_POST to get the data on same page.

i tried following

```
var t= timesheetId;//timesheet id is coming from js file 
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data: {'variable': t},
});
```

Comment: You need to send it somewhere, and process it in a `.php`-file separately. Specify a `url : "/phpfile.php",` parameter too, where you then use `$_POST['variable']` in a `phpfile.php`

Comment: If you're unsure of the basics of jQuery's AJAX functions [read this](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html).

Comment: i want  to post variable on same page

Comment: Without having too much details, it seems like you might be confused with client-side and server-side programming. You should read through [**this StackOverflow**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `url` to that ajax request so that it sends it to wherever your php file is. right now it's not being sent anywhere